# Splash screen iOS only shown on simulator and at wrong size

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen

When I use the code mentioned below, I get the desired splash screen with fade out on the iPhone simulator, but the picture seems to be zoomed with factor 2: I only get the upper left quarter of my initial picture (= launch image), zoomed to full screen. The launch image itself is shown in correct size at startup, before the splash screen kicks in.

Code is entered in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.

```
// Splash screen
    UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1357.png"]];
    [[navigationController view] addSubview:imageView];
    [[navigationController view] bringSubviewToFront:imageView];

    // as usual
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //now fade out splash image
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:4.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^(void){imageView.alpha=0.0f;} completion:^(BOOL finished){[imageView removeFromSuperview];}];
```

Furthermore the splash screen doesn't seem to appear on the device (iPhone 4S (Retina) with iOS 6.0), only on the simulator: when run on iPhone, it only displays the launch image.

What could be the cause and solution to both issues?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As for the fact that the splash screen didn't display on the device: this was caused by a difference in the filename. The extension in the code was in lower case, while the actual file had an upper case (PNG) extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Setup frame for imageView, otherwise it has the same sizes as an image
2. Setup correct contentMode
3. Try to use self.window, instead of [navigationController view]

Example:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1357.png"]];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.frame = self.window.bounds;
[self.window addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//now fade out splash image
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window
                  duration:4.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                animations:^(void) {
                    imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished ){
                    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
                }];
```

To add a 1 second pause before the fade out:

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.window
                      duration:4.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                    animations:^(void) {
                        imageView.alpha=0.0f;
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished ){
                        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
                    }];
});
```

or

```
[self performSelector:@selector(_hideSplash:) withObject:imageView afterDelay:1.0];

- (void) _hideSplash:(UIView *)view
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.window
                      duration:4.0f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                    animations:^(void) {
                        view.alpha=0.0f;
                    }
                    completion:^(BOOL finished ){
                        [view removeFromSuperview];
                    }];    
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!
1. and 2. solved my problem.
3. Didn't work for me: that change prevented my splash screen to show.

What do I have to change or add to add a 1 second pause before the fade out?
I would like to vote up, but don't seem to have earned enough reputation yet.. :(

Comment: I had updated example code to show how to add pause before fade out

Comment: @Andrey Soloviev I have a question, i'm trying this now, but its not working for me. Im a little confused on what you meant by "correct contentMode". Im new to this I should warn you :). But im learning story board as we speak. I implemented this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and changed the source image to mines, also in storyboard, I did a view controller, with an image view inside, and set the image to be visible as a separate one. Can you help me as to what might be wrong/missing?